# Powershell/Commandline in Modern UI

Tags: powershell, windows-8, command-line, modern-ui

Is there (or is possible) a standard Powershell or commandline in Modern UI in Win 8.x?

It would be pretty nice to have this app "docked" on a part of screen only (for SSH, etc...) and other desktop apps still could be in fullscreen.

Comment: I think this is off topic since it concerns general software and is not related to programming.

Comment: Agreed, off-topic, but I've thought the same thing. It'd be cool to have a PowerShell console host as a Modern App. Might have some permissions limitations, because I don't think they can run as administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't do this directly.  The PowerShell engine isn't available on WinRT.  You might be able to do something like create a WinRT app that uses sockets to communicate to a service on the localhost that executes PowerShell for you and returns the results. That would require you to build that service and install it on machines.  If this is for a Windows RT device that won't work because only Microsoft can install desktop apps.